# is it clear that what "it" refers to in the following sentence?

Tags: pronouns, reference

> Poverty seems to be the immediate cause of the unprecedented rate of
> crime. Lack of discipline also can be considered as the underlying
> cause of it.

Does "it" in the above text clearly refer to "the unprecedented rate of crime"? Or it is ambiguous? I think the distance between them is a bit large, so it may be problematic for the reader.

Comment: Is this your writing?

Comment: @JamesK Yep! I am practicing for IELTS task 2

Comment: Lack of discipline can also be considered as one of its underlying causes.

Comment: "Lack of discipline" sounds like my father circa 1957.

Comment: Side note: "... cause of it" is unnatural. "... can be considered *its* underlying cause" is more natural. And good luck on the test!!

Comment: I'm leaving this question open because it is not a request for proofreading. It clearly does "focus on something in particular that you are unsure about" (I'm quoting the message on that close flag), which is the possible ambiguity of "it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  it is understandable in context.

The first sentence introduces one cause of "the unprecedented rate of crime".

The second sentence introduces a second cause.

It's a bit unclear.  It says that poverty is the immediate cause. But "lack of discipline" is the underlying cause.  I'd understand this to mean that "lack of discipline" is the cause of poverty... which causes the rate of crime.

Also, does poverty cause the "rate" or the "crimes". At the moment it literally says that poverty causes the rate.

Comment: What if I change `the unprecedented rate of crime` to `unprecedented crime rate` !?

Comment: better.........